# Dimensional analysis of $x=t^2-2t-3$

Tags: kinematics, dimensional-analysis, si-units

Suppose a relation between distance of a particle $x$ and time $t$ as $x=t^2-2t-3$ where $x$ is in meters and $t$ is in seconds. We can differentiate $x$ w.r.t $t$ to get relation between velocity and time.

I think that how can the equation be dimensionally correct as its dimensions are like $[M^0L^1T^0]=[M^0L^0T^2]-[M^0L^0T^1]-[M^0L^0T^0]$ and by principle of homogeneity in dimensions the different dimensions can't be added so the equation is dimensionally incorrect.

So how can we do such operations(as differentiation) on it?

Comment: You are correct distance can't be equal to tike but here it is just a relation between x with time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase "[...] where $x$ is in meters and $t$ is in seconds" means that $x$ is a pure number which is equal to the position coordinate of your object divided by one meter.  The same goes for the time.

That is, you can think of your equation as being

$$\left(\frac{x}{1\text{ m}}\right)=\left(\frac{t}{1\text{ s}}\right)^2 - 2\left(\frac{t}{1\text{ s}}\right) - 3$$

This equation is dimensionally consistent (because all quantities are dimensionless), and is equivalent to

$$x = At^2 - 2 Bt - 3$$
where $A = 1$ m/s$^2$ and $B=1$ m/s.

Comment: Okay, now I get it.

Answer (score 5):

Dimensionally-inconsistent equations like this are intended to be understood in a dimensionless way in some system of units, such as

$$\frac{x}{1\text{ m}}= \left(\frac{ t}{1\text{ s}}\right)^2 -2\left( \frac{t}{1\text{ s}}\right) -3. $$

In this case, the the unit of length is the meter and the unit of time is the second, as stated in the problem.